# Feasibility of recovering radio transmission carrier frequency

Tags: high-frequency, frequency-measurement

Assuming you have an FM Radio transmission at 94.4MHz where the carrier frequency is generated by a rather accurate source (lets assume allan deviation \$10^{-12}\$), is it feasible to recover a sine wave at 94.4MHz (or even at 10MHz because thats standard for everyone) with a reasonable deviation without using an oscillator that is disciplined by it?

What would be a realistic deviation that we could achieve and what basic building blocks do we need?

Comment: What's a reasonable deviation? You want to recover the carrier and throw away the modulation?

Comment: Are you asking about phase locking a VCO to the FM carrier?

Comment: @GeorgeHerold: Kind of, but without any great performing oscillator.

Comment: @Samuel: Hard to tell what is reasonable as this is mostly a thought experiment about getting alternative sources of accurate frequencies, but something in the ballbark of an ok-ish frequency counters txco

Answer (score 2):

You can use a PLL to track the incoming signal's frequency. As long as the loop remains in lock — i.e., the phase error does not "wrap" beyond the phase detector's ability to deal with it — you can select the loop parameters to attenuate the modulation to a fairly arbitrary degree. The mean frequency of the PLL output will be the same as the mean frequency of the incoming signal, so it then becomes a question of how much deviation you can tolerate in the output.

Comment: @Dave_Tweed are there phase detectors that behave beyond 360 degrees? By my reckoning, FM radio must go far beyond this - imagine a 20 kHz deviation for 10 ms. Is there a detector that could cope?

Comment: @tomnexus: Yes, there are multi-cycle phase detectors. One simple approach is to put a digital frequency divider at each input to the phase detector, so that one full cycle there represents N cycles of the input signals. And there's no reason that N has to be the same for both inputs. You could divide by 944 on the signal input and divide by 100 on the feedback input and have the VC(X)O generate 10.000 MHz directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can only reasonably lock to the carrier frequency of an FM transmitter if it is transmitting only a carrier, with no modulation.
The very nature of FM (Frequency modulation) means that the modulation (voice, music, data, whatever) shifts the actual frequency.  There is no fixed carrier as there is with AM.

Comment: I'm most likely displaying my lack of understanding of FM, But I thought you still had a carrier with side bands.  I guess there is SSB and SSB-SC.  Is that how much FM radio is done?

Comment: @GeorgeHerold: Yes, there is a carrier, but unlike with AM, the amplitude of the carrier itself varies along with that of the sidebands in FM. With certain combinations of modulation frequency and modulation index, the carrier frequency can disappear altogether. Look up [Bessel functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation_synthesis#Spectral_analysis).

Comment: @DaveTweed, Yeah, I've done FM modulation in lotsa different ways, scroll down here for one... you have to modulate it a lot to get the carrier to go away.  http://www.teachspin.com/instruments/Fourier%20Methods/

Answer (score 0):

This might be quite a smart idea to build a cheap, accurate clock.

The FM transmitter frequency of a major station is quite likely governed by a GPS/Rb clock.

The audio is band limited to probably 50 Hz and up, so the long term Allan Deviation of the FM station will be as good as the GPS/Rb, possibly with some strange diurnal cycles for expansion of the feed transmission line.

Close in, faster than 50 Hz, the station will have quite a lot of phase noise (some call it music). You could clean that up with a good quartz oscillator and PLL, with a loop bandwidth well below 50 Hz. But you say you don't want another oscillator to discipline.

How about dividing the FM frequency down to around 10 MHz and then using a crystal filter to clean it up? The filter bandwidth would have to be below 50 Hz to keep the music out. Very hard to keep that filter stable, perhaps in an oven?

You might have more luck with a medium wave station - there you have a carrier and very little noise until maybe 100 Hz.